# Find typed string in text with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have input and text. I would like to find string which is typed in input in text using angular. What's best way to do this?

Something like [this](http://padolsey.github.io/findAndReplaceDOMText/demo.html) but using angular. It's important to me to have labeled search results.